# JSF selectOneMenu tag error while using a list 

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

I am using JSF tag h:selectOneMenu for a drop down List.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="subscriberName" value="#{manageSubscriberInformation.subscriberName}" 
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="" />                            
    <f:selectItems value="#{manageSubscriberInformation.subList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The subList object is a list which I have defined in my bean class with getter and setters. 
In my init method of my servlet I am populating the list with some values. 
But when I am loading the page I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collection referenced by UISelectItems with binding '#{manageSubscriberInformation.subList}' and Component-Path : {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/manageSubscriber.jsp][Class: javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer,Id: body][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlForm,Id: c][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu,Id: subscriberName][Class: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems,Id: _idJsp143]} does not contain Objects of type SelectItem
```

Not able to understand what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is rather self-explaining.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Collection referenced by UISelectItems (...) does not contain Objects of type SelectItem

The `#{manageSubscriberInformation.subList}` must return a `List<SelectItem>` or `SelectItem[]` where `SelectItem` is [the `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html).

Only since JSF 2.0, it is not required anymore to be specifically `SelectItem`.

#### See also:

- [Our `h:selectOneMenu` tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)